# CORS issue with nodejs and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

Good day to all of you. I'm trying to build a log in and right now im struggling with the register form, I'm using react js for FrontEnd and nodejs/express for BackEnd.

I created the register form, I'm putting data from this register form inside an object, parsing it to a JSON obj and sending it to the node server through fetch api, however the cors thing is not letting this happen, i'm not sure why. The next is the code from the register(front side)

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Register.css';
import Title from './Title/Title';
import Label from './Label/Label';
import Input from './Input/Input';


function Register(){

    const [ name, setName ] = useState('');
    const [ lastname, setLastname ] = useState('');
    const [ email, setEmail ] = useState('');
    const [ username, setUsername ] = useState('');
    const [ password, setPassword ] = useState('');

    function handleChange(name, value){
        if(name==='name')setName(value);
        else if (name==='lastname')setLastname(value);
        else if (name==='email')setEmail(value);
        else if (name==='username')setUsername(value);
        else if (name==='password')setPassword(value);
    }


    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let account = { name, lastname, email, username, password };
        if(account)console.log(account);

        var url = 'http://localhost:3030/';
        
        
        fetch(url, {
        method: 'OPTION', 
        body: JSON.stringify(account), 
        headers:{            
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        }).then(res => res.json()) 
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
       
        
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    }

    return(
        <div className='register-div'>
             <Title text='Register Form'/>
             <div className='squareout'>

             
            <div className='square'>
            <Label text='Name'/>
            <Input attribute={{type:'text', name:'name'}} handleChange={handleChange}/>
            </div>

            <div className='square'>
           <Label text='Last Name'/>
            <Input attribute={{type:'text', name:'lastname'}} handleChange={handleChange}/>
           </div>

           <div className='square'>
           <Label text='E-Mail'/>
            <Input attribute={{type:'text', name:'email'}} handleChange={handleChange}/>
           </div>
            
           <div className='square'>
           <Label text='Username'/>
            <Input attribute={{type:'text', name:'username'}} handleChange={handleChange}/>
           </div>
            
           <div className='square'>
            <Label text='Password'/>
            <Input attribute={{type:'password', name:'password'}} handleChange={handleChange}/>
            </div>
            
            

            </div>
            <button className='boton' onClick = {handleSubmit}>Register</button>
            
            
        </div>
    )
};

export default Register;
```

and this is from the server side:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3030;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Authorization, Origin, Accept");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
  next();
});

app.use(express.json());
app.post('http://localhost:3030/', (request, response) => {
console.log(request.body);
const data = request.body;
response.json({
  
    name: data.name,
    lastname: data.lastname,
    email: data.email,
    username: data.username,
    password: data.password
})
});
```

and yet I'm getting this error:
[image]

Line 33:  fetch(url, {

this is from the first code, the front side

Comment: Check this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58403651/react-component-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: there are many, many Stack Overflow questions about CORS issues and node.js servers running express. which of them have you researched, which answers have you tried, and why did they not solve your particular problem?

Comment: I did my reseach before posting, it happened that the solutions that I found did not help me, had nothing to do with my case, were too complicated for me, tried but didn't work.. or something else. I did not think it was important to quote them here, maybe I was wrong

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, you can use [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors)

And simply do:

```
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
app.use(cors())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply when facing an CORS issue remember these concepts,

1. It is not front-end apps fault (mostly)
2. you are trying to cross domain requests
3. those are blocked by default
4. You can allow this by `allowOrigins` with backend (syntax varies on language)
5. problem here is accessing localhost:3030 from localhost:3000

```js
    const express = require('express');
    const cors = require('cors');
    const app = express();
    app.use(cors())

  //for single origin
  var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // For legacy browser support
 }

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

[source](https://stackabuse.com/handling-cors-with-node-js/)

Answer (score 0):

If you set `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to`  `true` means you are allowing credentialed request

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true)
```

Then you can't set  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*(wildcard)`

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

**so solution here is that**,
you have to set specific origin here,(frontend app origin for reactjs by default its http://localhost:3000/)

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000/");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution, first instead of the method 'OPTION' I used 'POST' and the on the server side, i changed 'http://localhost:3030/' to just '/' and worked.